# How do i properly initialize a variable with a custom type

Tags: c#, database, initialization

This is the code in C#:

```
public bool IsNation(string country)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Nations.Count; i++)
        {

            if (Nations[i].Name == country)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else { return false; }

        }return true;

    }
```

In C# you must initialize variables. But what if you made one of your own like this below?

```
public class WorldMarket
    {
        public WorldMarket()
        {
            Nations = new List<NationBuilder>();
        }

        internal List<NationBuilder> Nations { get; set; }

        public void AddToWorldMarket(NationBuilder nation)
        {
            Nations.Add(nation);
        }
```

The main idea is that from this structure:

```
- wm
   - Nations
      - [0]
          - Name "USA"
          - stockpile 
            - [0]
                - Name "Coal"
                - Quantity "quantity"
                - Value "value"
      - [1] //Same as above
```

Find the country Name "USA" or whatever name inside this structure with a function that by only inserting a string with a name it outputs {1 or 0}
or True or False (if type == bool).

My attempt is the first code presented in this question. It tries to "travel" the structure and find the Name Tag you input as country using this call.

`IsNation(string country);` where country can be whatever string input.

**Question**
If C# wants me to declare every variable with an initial value, how do i do it with this custom or whatever custom type i may do?

Comment: For those wondering i haven't added the Exceptions yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the variable in the constructor public WorkdMarket(). See code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WorldMarket wm = new WorldMarket();
        }
    }
    public class WorldMarket
    {
        internal List<NationBuilder> Nations { get; set; }
        public WorldMarket()
        {
            Nations = new List<NationBuilder>() {
                new NationBuilder() { 
                    name = "USA", 
                    stockPiles = new List<StockPile>() {
                        new StockPile() { name = "Coal", quantity = 2, value = "value"},
                        new StockPile() { name = "Coal", quantity = 2, value = "value"}
                    }
                }
            };      
        }


        public void AddToWorldMarket(NationBuilder nation)
        {
            Nations.Add(nation);
        }
    }
    public class NationBuilder
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public List<StockPile> stockPiles { get; set; }
    }
    public class StockPile
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int quantity { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The line you requested would be:

```
WorldMarket con = new WorldMarket();
```

However, this would initialize as a new WorldMarket object, which has no pre-populated values yet. If the nations are meant to be static, you could initialize all the nations within the WorldMarket class

```
public class WorldMarket 
{
    public WorldMarket() 
    {
         Nations = new List<NationBuilder>() {
            new NationBuilder() { 
                name = "USA",
                ... 
            },
            new NationBuilder() {
                name = "AUS",
                ...
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Or alternatively if you could have your isNation method within WorldMarket, that might work better such that.

```
public class WorldMarket() 
{
    // various class constructor methods


    public int IsNation(string country)
    {
        // you could access Nations directly here
        for (int i = 0; i < Nations.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Nations[i].Name == country)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            // else { return 0; } -- this would exit the loop unnecessarily
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

and the usage in your main program would be something like

```
program static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WorldMarket con = new WorldMarket();
        con.AddToWorldMarket(new NationBuilder() {
            name = "USA",
            ... 
        }
        Console.WriteLine(con.IsNation("USA"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated the first code which is about the question. I did as you told me to insert it into WorldMarket class. The things now is that I am debugging it and it only does the for loop once! Right now I'm too stupid to see it.

Comment: I said nothing, i solved it by reading basic stuff i though i already knew from other languages.

Comment: Lol... sorry, I didn't check your for loop logic and simply copy-paste it. I suppose you've removed the else statement part of it already now...